# Jquery, Highcharts enable html exportChart

Tags: jquery, highcharts, legend, legend-properties

I have some chart with legend

```
legend: {
        useHTML: true,
        labelFormatter: function () {
            return '<img src="linkToPicture"><br>';

            //return this.name.replace(/\d+/g, '');
        }
    }
```

How can I save it with standart highchart functions? Problem is that HighCHart export saves text but not pictures, what is a reason of problem? P.S. Actually legend looks fine in browser, problem is with exporting chart. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `export` function of `Highcharts` connects to their server, so without an internet connection the export function will not work. Therefore I think the function works like this: it sends the data to the server and the server generates the `img` or `pdf` and sends back the file for us to save. So, your image will not be sent to the server to be exported, only the text.